# What the name for these things?

Tags: meaning, nouns, names

Could you please tell me, what these things are called in English.

---

N.B.
**monograms, ciphers, cartouches** don't fit the meaning

[image: Decorative scrollwork]

Comment: Looks like an **acanthus** motif.

Comment: These decorative patterns can sometimes be specifically defined and sometimes not. Heraldry and Greek architecture are two places where these types of designs were used. Yes, the acanthus leaf is on a Doric column, I believe. [Heraldry is a b***h, the terminology makes one pull out one's hair.:)]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general term for this is [*scroll decoration* or *scrollwork*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scroll_(art)).  This is most often seen in architecture, on buildings that emulate classical (Greek or Roman) or medieval (European) decoration.

[image]

[image]

Specifically, your example is of *foliated scrollwork*:

> In art history, a "floriated" or "flower scroll" has flowers, often in the centre of the volutes, and a "foliated" or "leaf scroll" shows leaves in varying degrees of profusion along the stems.

I'm not certain Lambie's answer of "whorls" is incorrect, since a *whorl* might be considered a subcategory of scrollwork:

Answer (score 1):

From BOTANY:

A whorl:

In botany, a whorl or verticil is an arrangement of sepals, petals, leaves, stipules or branches that radiate from a single point and surround or wrap around the stem.

[a whorl of leaves](http://In%20botany,%20a%20whorl%20or%20verticil%20is%20an%20arrangement%20of%20sepals,%20petals,%20leaves,%20stipules%20or%20branches%20that%20radiate%20from%20a%20single%20point%20and%20surround%20or%20wrap%20around%20the%20stem.[1]%20[2]%20A%20whorl%20consists%20of%20at%20least%20three%20elements;%20a%20pair%20of%20opposite%20leaves%20is%20not%20called%20a%20whorl.)

There are probably heraldry terms that might fit also. but whorl or whorl of leaves works well for your picture as two leaves come off a central stem.

[more definitions or examples for whorl](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/whorl)